# How to use API to repin from Shop to Board

Tags: pinterest

I want to repin something from :
https://www.pinterest.com/shop_pins/merchants/1813896619996231907/

to my board:
https://www.pinterest.com/clothfix/top-10-designs/

Is this possible with API?